# numpy sum performance on small arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have code that could make use of some speedup - unfortunately the bottle neck seems to be already in the numpy code. To my surprise `np.sum` function rather than my logarithms are consuming most of the time.

This is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import xlogy

p = np.random.rand(20,4)

def many_foo(p):
    for i in range(100000):
        foo(p)

def foo(p):
    p_bar = xlogy(p, p)
    p_sum = p_bar.sum()
    p_sum = np.sum(p_bar)
```

kern_prof (`%lprun -f foo many_foo(p)`) gives following line profiling:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 1.43734 s
File: <ipython-input-63-8f7d1e3cad35>
Function: foo at line 10

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    10                                           def foo(p):
    11    100000       259856      2.6     18.1      p_bar = xlogy(p, p)
    12    100000       404256      4.0     28.1      p_sum = p_bar.sum()
    13    100000       773232      7.7     53.8      p_sum = np.sum(p_bar)
```

The results are surprising to me. `p_bar.sum()` outcompeting `np.sum(p_bar)` by a factor of 2 might hint towards hitting calling overhead issues.

But why is calculating the logarithm so fast compared to the sum? And is there any hope in getting this faster without switching to c++?

Note that the small dimensions of `p` is representative of the problem I have to solve.

Comment: I am getting comparable runtimes for `xlogy(p, p)` and `np.sum(p_bar)` using `%timeit`.

Comment: timeit is the same for me `np.sum` is 2.5 times slower. Maybe continuum's mkl blas library is responsible... hmhm

Comment: @Divakar, for me with `p = np.random.rand(20,4)` `xlogy` outperforms `np.sum` by at least a factor of two on macos numpy (mkl and openblas) also on linux numpy (mkl).

Comment: The `np.sum` does become `2x` slower when I further reduce the datasize : `p = np.random.rand(5,4)`. So, could be hardware/resources dependent too.

Comment: Also, the function call overhead for `np.sum` is much more than (more than 2x) that for `xlogy` and that shows up for those small datasets.